# How do I disable products in Kentico 10?

Tags: kentico

I am performing CRUD operations for products of e-commerce site in kentico 10.I can add and update products using below API

```
SKUInfoProvider.SetSKUInfo(updateProduct);
```

Also there is an API for deleting product

```
SKUInfoProvider.DeleteSKUInfo(updateProduct);
```

But I do not wish to delete the product from database,rather just disable them so that they do not show up to the end users and still stay in the database .

This are the SKU Objects for the product :

```
var sku = new SKUInfo
            {
                //SKUName = Convert.ToString(dr["SHORT_DESCRIPTION"]).Trim('"') + " (" + Convert.ToString(dr["MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER"]) + ")",
                SKUName = Convert.ToString(dr["MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER"]),
                SKUDescription = Convert.ToString(dr["TECHNICAL_SPECIFICATIONS"]).Trim('"'),
                SKUShortDescription = Convert.ToString(dr["SHORT_DESCRIPTION"]).Trim('"'),
                SKUPrice = ValidationHelper.GetDouble(dr["RESELLER_BUY_INC"], 0),
                SKURetailPrice = ValidationHelper.GetDouble(dr["RRP_INC"], 0),
                SKUEnabled = true,
                SKUSiteID = siteId,
                SKUProductType = SKUProductTypeEnum.Product,
                SKUManufacturerID = manufacturer.ManufacturerID,
                SKUDepartmentID = department.DepartmentID,
                SKUHeight = 100,
                SKUWidth = 100,
                SKUAvailableItems = 1,
                SKUSellOnlyAvailable = true
            };
```

I tried to set SKUEnabled as false but still user can see the product.So, is there any property to disable products ?

Comment: When you say user, are you talking about a user logging into the Kentico Admin interface or an end user on your website viewing your products?

Comment: yes  the end user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you displaying the Sku?  If it's a repeater, you may need to filter by the "SKUEnabled = 1" in your where condition.

Another option is if the Product has a Page (it's not a stand alone sku) you can unpublish the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well... A user doesn't see products per say - he sees pages that are connected to your SKUs/products. When you disable the SKU - the page is still visible, but  (if I am not mistaken) "Add To Cart" is not shown. You need to unpublish product pages. You need to set DocumentPublishTo of the document to some date before for ex:

ProductNode.SetValue("DocumentPublishTo", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));

Comment: If unpublishing is the goal, simply setting the PublishTo date to `DateTime.Now` would work - "now" is already in the past :)