# Hide a product in Kentico 10

Tags: kentico

I am performing CRUD operations for products of e-commerce site in kentico 10.I can add and update products using below API

```
SKUInfoProvider.SetSKUInfo(updateProduct);
```

Also there is an API for deleting product

```
SKUInfoProvider.DeleteSKUInfo(updateProduct);
```

But I do not wish to delete the product from database,rather just disable them so that they do not show up to the end users and still stay in the database .

I tried to set SKUEnabled as false but still user can see the product.So, I used below code to hide the products

```
ProductNode.SetValue("DocumentPublishTo", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
```

But my code setup adds a new product with above disabled property.Here is my code

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {                
            manufacturer = GetManufacturer(Convert.ToString(dr["MANUFACTURER_NAME"]));
            department = GetDepartment(Convert.ToString(dr["CATEGORY_OF_PRODUCT_1"]));

            var sku = new SKUInfo
            {
                SKUNumber = Convert.ToString(dr["MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER"]),
                SKUName = Convert.ToString(dr["MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER"]),
                SKUDescription = Convert.ToString(dr["TECHNICAL_SPECIFICATIONS"]).Trim('"'),
                SKUShortDescription = Convert.ToString(dr["SHORT_DESCRIPTION"]).Trim('"'),
                SKUPrice = ValidationHelper.GetDouble(dr["RESELLER_BUY_INC"], 0),
                SKURetailPrice = ValidationHelper.GetDouble(dr["RRP_INC"], 0),
                SKUEnabled = false,
                SKUSiteID = siteId,
                SKUProductType = SKUProductTypeEnum.Product,
                SKUManufacturerID = manufacturer.ManufacturerID,
                SKUDepartmentID = department.DepartmentID,
                SKUHeight = ValidationHelper.GetDouble(dr["HEIGHT"], 0),
                SKUWidth = ValidationHelper.GetDouble(dr["WIDTH"], 0),
                SKUWeight = ValidationHelper.GetDouble(dr["WEIGHT"], 0),
                SKUDepth = ValidationHelper.GetDouble(dr["LENGTH"], 0),
                SKUAvailableItems = 1,
                SKUSellOnlyAvailable = true
            };

            try
            {

                SKUInfo updateProduct = SKUInfoProvider.GetSKUs()
                                .WhereEquals("SKUNumber", sku.SKUNumber)
                                .FirstObject;

                sku.SKUPrice += sku.SKUPrice * 0.015;


                if (updateProduct != null)
                {
                    updateProduct.SKUNumber = sku.SKUNumber; updateProduct.SKUName = sku.SKUName;
                    SKUInfoProvider.SetSKUInfo(updateProduct);
                }

                else
                {
                    SKUInfoProvider.SetSKUInfo(sku);
                }

                if (!sku.SKUEnabled)
                {
                    SKUTreeNode productDoc = (SKUTreeNode)SKUTreeNode.New(productDocumentType.ClassName, tree);
                    if (sku.SKUEnabled == false)
                    {
                        productDoc.DocumentPublishTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    }

                    productDoc.DocumentSKUName = Convert.ToString(dr["MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER"]);
                    productDoc.DocumentSKUDescription = sku.SKUDescription;
                    productDoc.NodeSKUID = sku.SKUID;
                    productDoc.DocumentCulture = cultureCode;
                    productDoc.DocumentName = Convert.ToString(dr["MANUFACTURER_PART_NUMBER"]);

                }
            }                

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                error += "error";
            }

        }
```

Please provide the possible solution.There ain't no property such as DocumentPublishTo in SKUInfo,hence I used it with SKUTreeNode which you can find in code setup.

```
  SKUTreeNode productDoc = (SKUTreeNode)SKUTreeNode.New(productDocumentType.ClassName, tree);
                if (sku.SKUEnabled == false)
                {
                    productDoc.DocumentPublishTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                }
```

Comment: why do you call (SKUTreeNode)SKUTreeNode.New() when you don't want a new product? I would set it for updateProduct object instead.

Comment: There ain't no property such as DocumentPublishTo in SKUInfo,hence used it with SKUTreeNode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable products in Kentico 10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114600/how-do-i-disable-products-in-kentico-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the node for the SKU, not create a new one. from the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/api9/e-commerce/products#Products-Updatingaproductpage) :

```
    SKUTreeNode productDoc = (SKUTreeNode)tree.SelectNodes()
        .Path("/Products/NewProduct")
        .OnCurrentSite()
        .CombineWithDefaultCulture()
        .FirstObject;
productDoc.DocumentPublishTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
```